# awk conditional line numbering

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

I'm trying to put numbers before each line in file but only if the value in second column (field) is different than preceding

input file:

```
11:10PM *Jane> login
11:15PM *Bob>  login
11:16PM *Bob>  logout
11:45PM *Betty> login
01:20AM *John>  login
```

output:

```
1. 11:10PM *Jane> login
2. 11:15PM *Bob>  login
   11:16PM *Bob>  logout
3. 11:45PM *Betty> login
4. 01:20AM *John> login
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Takes advantage of the fact that variables have default values in **awk**:

```
{
  if (last == $2) {
    printf("    %s\n", $0)
  } else {
    n += 1;
    last = $2;
    printf("%2d. %s\n", n, $0);
  }
}
```

This uses *n* to remember how many entries have been seen and *last* to remember the last entry seen.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{print (seen[$2]++ ? "   " : sprintf("%2d.",++cnt)), $0}' file
 1. 11:10PM *Jane> login
 2. 11:15PM *Bob>  login
    11:16PM *Bob>  logout
 3. 11:45PM *Betty> login
 4. 01:20AM *John>  login
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind it?

Comment: Clean and smart, as usual! :)

Comment: @Sadhun given your recent comments asking for an explanation on a couple of my posts of trivial answers, you need to read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. That'll be much more efficient than if I explain how awk works script by script.